# WorkManager custom initialization complains about WorkManager#initialize

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

With:
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4"

I'm trying to implement custom initialization to enable more verbose logging [according to these instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#java).

The first snippet has one line bad: `return Configuration.Builder()` needs to be `return new Configuration.Builder()`.

I extended Application as shown like this:

```
class MyApplication extends Application implements Configuration.Provider {
    @Override
    public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I initiate the worker like this:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

And yet even after all of that I get the application to crash with this complaint:

> WorkManager is not initialized properly. You have explicitly disabled
> WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called
> WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not
> implement Configuration.Provider.

Even though the instructions states:

> You do not need to call WorkManager.initialize() yourself

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to this link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#custom

OR

Initialize your custom WorkManager like this:

```
// provide custom configuration
val myConfig = Configuration.Builder()
    .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
    .build()

// initialize WorkManager
WorkManager.initialize(this, myConfig)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the [`Configuration.Provider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Provider) interface in your Application class to provide a custom configuration using WorkManager's [on-demand initialization](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand).

This is explained with some sample code in the [Advanced WorkManager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/#3):

```
class BlurApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration = 

        Configuration.Builder()
                     .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
                     .build()
...
}
```

Please be sure to have this Application class included in you `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application
        android:name=".BlurApplication"
```

Doing so, the first time you request WorkManager instance with [`getInstance(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getInstance(android.content.Context)) the library will be initialized with your custom configuration.

Comment: I already have done so. Look at my updated question , I've shown this code in Java.

Comment: Are you sure to have imported  Configuration.Provider from `androidx.work.Configuration`?  
Also have you updated you AndroidManifest to use your Application class?

Comment: Yes, and do you mean with <provider> like this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#remove-default ?

Comment: No, I mean in the `<application` block. I've added this step to the answer.

Comment: When i tell the IDE to implemente the method, it does the following


```class MyApplication(override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration) : MultiDexApplication(), Configuration.Provider {
...
}```

What should o do?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Manifest.xml inside the application tag.

```
<application>

   <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove">
        </provider>

   <application>
```